LaTeX does not compile the whole abstract command
Basic information:
I am writing a thesis using PdfLaTeX in TexMaker, based on a modified template provided by my university. The document is styled using a .cls file, and I am managing the bibliography with a .bib file, using Biber as the backend.
The .cls file has a \abstractpage command defined.
The command in the .cls file is defined as:
\newcommand{\abstractpage}[6]{ %definicja strony ze streszczeniami

\setstretch{1.4} % od tego miejsca interlinia 1.5; pierwotnie ustawiono \onehalfspacing ale obecna wersja bardziej odpowiada wersji .doc

\null
\vfill
\begin{center}
    \textbf{Streszczenie}\\
\end{center}
    \noindent
    \textbf{#1}\\[1.5ex]
    {#2}
    \\[4ex]
    S{\l}owa kluczowe -- {#3}

\vfill
\begin{center}
    \textbf{Summary}\\
\end{center}
    \noindent
    \textbf{#4}\\[1.5ex]
    \\[4ex]
\vfill
\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\null
\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
}

and used in the .tex file as:
\abstractpage
{title PL}
{Some text}
{tags}
{title EN}
{some text}
{tags}

Error:
The problem I receive is that not the whole text provided in \abstractpage is compiled in the document. Specifically, the text and tags of the English summary are missing. The compiler does not output any error.

I expect it to look like this:


During running a not modified version of the template, the error does not occur.
I copy-pasted the whole command once again (from the default file) but it does not help.
Using the \abstractpage command in a plain file does reproduce this error in my case.
The whole .cls file can be found in the GitHub repository here.

I suspect, that the commands somehow conflict with each other or the syntax could be wrong somewhere, but I cannot detect in which place.

What's the difference between the modified and unmodified versions?  Which text are you wondering about?  If it's the "some text" and "tags" following the "title EN", that's because you've deleted the #5 and #6 that would use those arguments.  Otherwise, can you put this command into a complete document so that we can compile and see the same result?

as the comment above says you have a definition that takes 6 arguments but does not use #5 or #6 so those two text arguments do not get used. what output did you expect?

Hello, I edited the post.
The \abstractpage should not be changed between template and abstract. I just want to change the inputs between old and new(thesis) .tex files.

I solved the problem thanks to you. I wish you all the best.

please do no edit answers in to question posts, it spoils the question and answer format of the site. Glad you got it working bit I'll vote to close as unclear as there wasn't really enough information for anyone but you to answer.

How come this question is closed for "lacking details or clarity" when there was enough information in the question for Teepeemm to figure out the answer? The asker clearly made an effort to condense his problem to an MCVE. What more do you expect?

@Joooeey AFAIK Teepeemm only moved the answering code from the question to a new answer. See the revisions for the change. This is also the reason to declare the answer as community wiki. Nevertheless, IMHO it is still not easy to reproduce the problem with a single copy&paste, because there isn't a minimal working example in the question. See also David's comment about why to close the question although a kind of answer is available.

@cabohah the answer is given in the first two comments by Teepeemm and David, like 16 hours before the question was edited to include an explanation why that mistake was made. Those two comments explain the issue better than the community wiki answer. Ideally, those could be converted into an answer but obviously that can't be done when the question is closed.

I added a sentence at the top of the answer that clarifies what was going on.  To be honest, I added the community answer when I saw this was in danger of being closed even though we'd figured out the solution (I don't think @Joooeey is able to see that I did not vote to close).  My preferred outcome would be for this question to be reopened, and OP to accept the answer (or create their own if they want the points).  I'm guessing this question will end up being reopened, but my experience tells me there's a good chance OP will never be seen again.

As noted in the comments, the original command took 6 arguments (the \newcommand{\abstractpage}[6]), but did not use #5 nor #6.
From OP: I managed it to work. The correct version of the function looks like this:
\newcommand{\abstractpage}[6]{ %definicja strony ze streszczeniami

\setstretch{1.4} % od tego miejsca interlinia 1.5; pierwotnie ustawiono \onehalfspacing ale obecna wersja bardziej odpowiada wersji .doc

\null
\vfill
\begin{center}
    \textbf{Streszczenie}\\
\end{center}
    \noindent
    \textbf{#1}\\[1.5ex]
    {#2}
    \\[4ex]
    S{\l}owa kluczowe -- {#3}

\vfill
\begin{center}
    \textbf{Summary}\\
\end{center}
    \noindent
    \textbf{#4}\\[1.5ex]
    {#5}
    \\[4ex]
    Keywords -- {#6}
\vfill
\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\null
\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
}

The template was using \selecthyphenation{english} before #n, which provided me a different error. I incautiously removed the entire line containing \selecthyphenation{english}#n, which resolved the error but resulted in reduced output.
